# Custom login mechanism for a ASP.NET website

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, authentication

I'm working on a ASP.NET website and I need to get away with some custom but simple login mechanism. I started from the famous [Employee Info Starter Kit](http://eisk.codeplex.com/)

Here's what I have so far:

**On a ASP.NET page:**

```
protected void ButtonLogOn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUserName.Value) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPassword.Value))
        labelMessage.Text = MessageFormatter.GetFormattedErrorMessage("You can login using a username and a password associated with your account. Make sure that it is typed correctly.");
    else
    {
        //if the log-in is successful
        LoginPage LoginBack = new LoginPage();

        if (LoginBack.VerifyCredentials(txtUserName.Value, txtPassword.Value) == 0)
        {
            SiteLogin.PerformAuthentication(txtUserName.Value, checkBoxRemember.Checked);
        }
        else
        {
            labelMessage.Text = MessageFormatter.GetFormattedErrorMessage("<strong>Login Failed!</strong><hr/>The username and/or password you entered do not belong to any User account on our system.<br/>You can login using a username and a password associated with your account. Make sure that it is typed correctly.");
        }
    }
}

protected void ButtonAdminLogOn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUserName.Value) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPassword.Value))
        labelMessage.Text = MessageFormatter.GetFormattedErrorMessage("<strong>Login Please!</strong><hr/>You can login using a username and a password associated with your account. Make sure that it is typed correctly.");
    else
    {
        //if the log-in is successful
        if (txtUserName.Value == "admin" && txtPassword.Value == "123123")
        {
            SiteLogin.PerformAdminAuthentication("admin", checkBoxRemember.Checked);
        }
        else
        {
            labelMessage.Text = MessageFormatter.GetFormattedErrorMessage("<strong>Login Failed!</strong><hr/>The username and/or password you entered do not belong to any Administrator ccount on our system.<br/>You can login using a username and a password associated with your account. Make sure that it is typed correctly.");
        }
    }
}
```

**And a utility class**

```
public static void PerformAuthentication(string userName, bool remember)
{
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userName, remember);

    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] == null)
    {
        RedirectToDefaultPage();
    }
    else
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]);
    }
}

public static void PerformAdminAuthentication(string userName, bool remember)
{
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userName, remember);

    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] == null)
    {
        RedirectToAdminDefaultPage();
    }
    else
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]);
    }
}
```

My login form has two buttons: The Admin login is hard-coded name/password. The normal login routine goes back to another assembly that calls a web service and get the username and password checked against a domain login.

Now, there is one other file that has code and is baffling me.

**Global.asax**

```
<script RunAt="server">
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.User != null)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.AuthenticationType != "Forms")
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Only forms authentication is supported, not " +
                        HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.AuthenticationType);
            }

            IIdentity userId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;

            //if role info is already NOT loaded into cache, put the role info in cache
            if (HttpContext.Current.Cache[userId.Name] == null)
            {
                string[] roles;

                if (userId.Name == "admin")
                {
                    roles = new string[1] { "administrators" };
                }
                else if (userId.Name == "member1")
                {
                    roles = new string[1] { "employees" };
                }
                else
                {
                    roles = new string[1] { "public" };
                }

                //1 hour sliding expiring time. Adding the roles in cache. 
                //This will be used in Application_AuthenticateRequest event located in Global.ascx.cs 
                //file to attach user Principal object.
                HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add(userId.Name, roles, null, DateTime.MaxValue, TimeSpan.FromHours(1), CacheItemPriority.BelowNormal, null);
            }

            //now assign the user role in the current security context
            HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(userId, (string[])HttpContext.Current.Cache[userId.Name]);
        }
    }

}
</script>
```

The website has a few About pages that allow free access but the rest is either for admin or employee. My admin username/password is fixed but the employee login is entered in domain format and needs to be verified on target domain (all being done) and then set the employee role.

How am I to do that in the Application_AuthenticateRequest method in Global.asax file?

Comment: First, you can check auth mode on Application_Start, so don't check on every Application_AuthenticateRequest.

Comment: Good suggestion @abatishchev. Done that.

Comment: I wonder if I use the `LoginBack.VerifyCredentials(txtUserName.Value, txtPassword.Value)` in the `Global.asax`'s `Application_AuthenticateRequest()` method.

Comment: Also `<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="Namespace.Global" Language="C#" %>` allows to keep the global code within a code-behind file, what is much more handy. Try and you will enjoy that :)

Comment: Try to use `asp:Login` control and its [various events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login_events.aspx) like `LoggingIn` where you can use different auth techniques on your own. Also you can extend it to add more buttons and handle them differently.

Answer (score 1):

Set different auth modes for different folders (via [Web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178683.aspx) or even just [IIS snap-in](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733010%28WS.10%29.aspx)):

- Anonymous for root (with about pages)
- Forms auth for ~/Admin area
- Windows/NTLM for ~/Employers area

---

Also you can use extended [Login control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.aspx) with custom [Membership provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.aspx).

Comment: I cannot use Windows/NTLM as the website will always run on a machine not connected to any domain and I'll be using PrincipleContext and UserContext. So it's Form Authentication.

Comment: @HassanGulzar: So you actually use forms auth, take credentials given and check against a domain, correct?

Comment: Yup, the very basic of authentication just to get the user to enter name and password. once I get them, I go back another assembly and get the remaining domain-necessary info.

Comment: @HassanGulzar: Ok, got it. Have you checked out the Login control as I've suggested above? It can be deconstructed into cascade table and extended on your own. It uses current [membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx) provider to auth users. You can create your own, check user name against hardcoded list first, then bypass to your "pseudo domain auth" assembly.